# Oracle Case Statement Expression usage, and TRUE/FALSE usage

Tags: sql, oracle

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm)
for the Case Statement:

> The CASE statement evaluates a single expression and compares it against several potential values

It appears that I can put expressions in the case statement that evaluate to a number, such as `A + B`, but I can't put an expression that evaluates to a boolean such as `A = B`. I am forced to put the expression in the when clause. I would expect Oracle to treat TRUE and FALSE as 1 and 0 and apply the same rules to them.

Why is this not valid?

**Boolean Expressions Do Not Execute**

```
-- boolean expression  in case statement compared to 1 and 0
select case a = b
         when 1 then
          'EQUAL'
         else
          'NOT EQUAL'
       end as _RESULT
  from dual;

--boolean expression  in case statement compared to TRUE and FALSE
select case a = b
         when TRUE then
          'EQUAL'
         else
          'NOT EQUAL'
       end as _RESULT
  from dual;
```

**Numeric Expressions Do Execute**

```
--numeric expression in case statement compared to the number 3
select case a + b
         when 3 then
          'THREE'
         else
          'NOT THREE'
       end as _RESULT
  from dual;
```

**Boolean Expressions in the When Clause Do Execute**

```
select case
         when a = b then
          'EQUAL'
         else
          'NOT EQUAL'
       end as _RESULT
  from dual;
```

Comment: You can use  `CASE a WHEN b THEN true_aprt` - it is the same as `CASE WHEN a=b THEN true_part`. But I can't understand why don't you want to use `select case
         when a = b then
          'EQUAL'`. And there is no BOOLEAN data type in Oracle SQL. Only in PL/SQL

Comment: Good points @Tatiana. I understand that I can get the result in other ways, I was just curious why I can't use a boolean expression in the case clause.

Comment: As Tatiana stated, the principal reason is that Oracle SQL does not have a boolean datatype.  The `CASE a WHEN b THEN WHEN c THEN ... END` is mostly handy for those situations where your `a` expression may have numerous values (saves the trouble of retyping `a` when `a` is a complex function).  But since boolean only has two possible branches, I don't see where the savings would be in supporting the CASE breakout on TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: Oracle SQL has no boolean data type, so it also does not support boolean literals. This is a bit different in PL/SQL, but your question only contains plain SQL. The link you are referring to is for the CASE statement in PL/SQL, not the one in SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you point me to the non-pl/sql CASE statement documentation for oracle?

Comment: It's in the SQL reference, not the PL/SQL reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037